# React don't render mapping elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm mapping Array and React don't want to render this.
Typescript gives this error: "*This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'ReactNode', but multiple children were provided.*".
But when I use React fragment in component instead of div error isn't detected.
Why React don't render?

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export const VkForm = () => {

    const messages = useSelector((state: appStateType) => state.MessageReducer.Messages)

    return (<div>
                {messages.map((m) => {
                    <div key={m._id}>{m.text}</div>
                })}
    </div>)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common mistake for beginners. You are missing the actual return statement in your `.map` function.

Since you are using curly brackets you have to explicity add the `return` statement before your JSX Component like:

```
{messages.map((m) => {
    return <div key={m._id}>{m.text}</div>
})}
```

If you want to avoid explicitly returning that Component you can use the implicit return with parentheses:

```
{messages.map((m) => (
    <div key={m._id}>{m.text}</div>
))}
```